# How to call a macro using if condition in DBT?

Tags: macros, dbt

I have macro that will check the db name. I want to call this macro in my sql script and perform union if there is a  result from my macro . How can I do this?

select abc from books

if {{get_db_name()}} == TRUE
UNION

select abc from book_2;

Answer (score 0):

You'll want your code to look a little like this:

```
select abc from books

{% if get_db_name() == True %}
  UNION

  select abc from book_2
{% endif %}
```

That said, do you know about the `target` variable?  It allows you to key off target name, target database etc which might be a better option of doing what you want.

Comment: I'm not sure of this, but it seems the `target` variable is not avaliable to folks in DBT Cloud

Comment: @IliaGilmijarow it absolutely is!